# Rasa on telegram for multiple users at once

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot, rasa, rasa-core

Encountered a problem while deploying rasa on telegram, I used ngrok as suggested in the docs, but when two guys were testing the bot for registration purposes, the email got exchanged, guy1 successfully registered with his email while guy2 was shown the details of his own but the email on his part was of guy1.

Is there any session that we can use in order to prevent the exchanging/misleading messages as I want to deploy this bot to production.